# How to display excerpt for custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I need help with custom post type excerpt. I managed to add to `function.php` to get the excerpt showing on the edit page. Now I can find how to display it on the `taxonomy.php` file Need to replace that:(Which shows post content)

```
<p><?php echo tfuse_get_short_text($holiday['post_content'],10); ?></p>
```

By something to show post excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It may be helpful for you.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'custom-post-typename' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
the_excerpt();
endwhile;
```

Comment: Put this code in file wherever you want to display it

Answer (score 0):

If you already have POST object or post_id, you can do like this where you need:

```
echo get_the_excerpt( post object or post ID );
```

or if you in a loop, you can use get_the_excerpt() function without any variables.

You can read more about this here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/ .

I hope it's helpful for you.